# Is it possible to transpose tbl_summary table (Pivot table)

Tags: gtsummary

I would want to create a pivot table using the dataframe using tbl_summary

```
head(tblbdcc)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  ntdcc    miphlycc anopmcrpcc anomcrtcc cleftscc impanuscc hypcc talipcc limbcc omphcc gascc
  <fct>    <fct>     <dbl+lbl> <fct>     <fct>    <fct>     <fct> <fct>   <fct>  <fct>  <fct>
1 Cases    NA               NA NA        NA       NA        NA    NA      NA     NA     NA   
2 NA       Cases            NA NA        NA       NA        NA    NA      NA     NA     NA   
3 Controls NA               NA NA        NA       NA        NA    NA      NA     NA     NA   
4 Controls NA               NA NA        NA       NA        NA    NA      NA     NA     NA   
5 Controls NA               NA NA        NA       NA        NA    NA      NA     NA     NA   
6 NA       NA               NA NA        NA       NA        Cases NA      NA     NA     NA

tblbdscc <- tblbdcc %>%
     tbl_summary( 
      missing = "no",
      statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{n}"
)
```

I would want to transform the table from
[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pivot table in gtsummary, but you can construct the table one row at a time and stack the resulting tables. Example below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.2
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'
set.seed(11234)

# simulate data
df <- 
  tibble(
    ntdcc = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), 20, replace = TRUE),
    gascc = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), 20, replace = TRUE),
    limbcc = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), 20, replace = TRUE)
  )

# loop over every column in df to construct table
tbl <- 
  names(df) %>%
  map(
    # build summary table for single category
    ~ df %>%
      select(all_of(.x)) %>%
      mutate(..true.. = TRUE) %>%
      filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = all_of(.x),
        missing = "no",
        statistic = ~"{n}", 
        label = list(..true.. = .x)
      ) %>%
      # update column headers
      modify_header(
        all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**",
        label = "**Category Assigned**"
      )
  ) %>%
  # stack all tbls together
  tbl_stack() %>%
  # remove all footnotes
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.
I got an error: "Error in select(., all_of(.x)) : unused argument (all_of(.x))", but I resolved it by dplyr::select(all_of(.x)). Thanks again for your assistance.